# If G is open and dense subset in $\mathbb R$ then show that $G\setminus\{x\}$ is also open and dense in R. is it true in general metric space?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, examples-counterexamples, baire-category

If $G$ is open and dense subset in $\mathbb R$ then show that $G\setminus\{x\}$ is also open and dense in $\mathbb R$.  is it true in general metric space?

I know as $G$ is open and singleton set $\{x\}$ is closed so that $G\setminus\{x\}$ has to be open, but how to show it is dense in $\mathbb R$. next the same will true in general Metric space.

Comment: Try proving by contradiction. That is, assume $G\setminus \{x\}$ is not dense.

Comment: Then there is a point $y\in \Bbb{R}$ which lies in an interval $I$ that doesn't meet $G\setminus \{x\}$. But $I$ meets $G$ because $G$ is dense. The question is: how can $I$ meet $G$ but not meet $G\setminus \{x\}$?

Comment: If $I\cap G\ne \phi$ and $I\cap \left(G\setminus \{x\}\right) = \phi$, then $x$ is an isolated point of $G$. But $\Bbb{R}$ has no isolated points.

Answer (score 3):

Take as your universe an interval and an isolated point. 
As universe it is open and dense. Remove the isolated point, what remains is open
(as its complement is the closed point) but sadly not dense anymore.

For your question you would need the property that every point is a density point of the universe (or the dense set).

Comment: How can we say  single point set is dense in R? it is not true.

Comment: @user145993:  We do not say a single point is dense in $\Bbb R$. He chose a different base set.  The single point is still not dense, but the whole set is dense.

Answer (score 3):

It's not true in a general metric space.  Let $X$ be a metric space consisting of a single point $x$, with define $d(x,x) = 0$.  Then $G = \{x\}$ is open and dense in $X$, but $G \setminus \{x\} = \emptyset$ is no longer dense.

Answer (score 1):

First, we prove that $G-\{x\}$ is open and dense in general topological space $X$ of $T_2$ (Hausdorff space) and above.

Since $G-\{x\}=G\cap \{x\}^c$, and $\{x\}^c$ is open ($\{x\}$ is closed), $G-\{x\}$ is open.

Next we prove that $(G-\{x\})^c$ is nowhere dense in $X$. Since 
$$
(G-\{x\})^c=(G\cap \{x\}^c)^c=G^c\cup \{x\}
$$
if $\varnothing\ne O\subset(G-\{x\})^c$, $O$ is open, then $O\subset G^c$ for $\{x\}$ is closed, and so $O\subset (G^c)^o$. Since $G$ is dense in $X$, $G^c$ is nowhere dense in $X$, i.e. $(G^c)^o=\varnothing$. But this means that $O=\varnothing$, contradiction. Thus $(G-\{x\})^c$ is nowhere dense in $X$, and $(G-\{x\})$ is dense in $X$.

**Edit:**
Since $\Bbb{R}$ is Hausdorff space, above hold in $\Bbb{R}$. 
For general metric space that $X$ has isolated point, above doesn't hold.

Comment: Your argument assumes that $X$ has no isolated points.

Comment: Yes, $X$ has no isolated points, which is true for most spaces like metric space

Comment: And the counter-example below?

Comment: So you're saying that a non-discrete metric space has no isolated points? By the way, the OP's question makes no such assumption.

Comment: No, the OP had two questions.

Comment: I think you're incorrect when you say that discrete metric spaces are the only spaces with isolated points. There's no such result.

Comment: You should provide the result, if it's true.

Comment: You made the claim that a metric space with an isolated point must be discrete. Prove it or refer to the result in some text. I'm saying it's false.

Comment: I down voted you're answer because you made an assumption (about isolated points) that wasn't in the OP's question. You are also making claims which are false.

Comment: This is a well known conclusion in Baire Category. So it is right in most cases. I just exclude the discrete topology case (and finite topology case as in another post) that is rarely used.

Comment: Give a precise reference. Quote text and theorem number.

Comment: $[0,1] \cup \{2\}$ is a non-discrete metric space with an isolated point. Regarding your last paragraph, let me point out that a metric space is always Hausdorff...

Comment: Nice example Najib.

Comment: Here's where your proof falls down: "[I]f $\varnothing\ne O\subset(G-\{x\})^c,$ $O$ is open, then $O\subset G^c$ for $\{x\}$ is closed." Remember that sets are not doors! The fact that $\{x\}$ is closed does *not* mean that $\{x\}$ is non-open.

Comment: Although, there are sets that are both open and closed, $\{x\}$ is clearly not open in Hausdorff space, and not in $R$. The reason is simple. If $\{x\}$ is open, then any set is open too since arbitrary union of open sets is open in Hausdorff space.

Answer (score 0):

$G\setminus\{x\}$ will be dense whenever $\{x\}$ isn't open, which, as stated in other answers, is true as long as $x$ isn't an isolated point.

An example that I like where this happens (and isn't just discrete where every subset is open) is $X=\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}^+\}\cup\{0\}$ viewed as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$. So the metric on it is the usual metric on the real numbers. In this space, every point except 0 is isolated, while 0 isn't isolated because it has points arbitrarily close to it.

And to see this is a counterexample to the property you are asking about, $X\setminus\{1\}$ is not dense, since it doesn't intersect $\{1\}$ which must be open because it equals $\{x\in X:|x-1|<\frac{1}{4}\}$.